# get UDP Multicast stream in PHP

Tags: php, udp, video-streaming, multicast

I am trying to receive a UDP multicast stream in PHP. The receive command never gets anything and waits forever.

I can watch the stream using VLC player so the stream is accessible on my machine. Any help on how to do this using PHP is highly appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

//create a new socket

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
```

//i am not sure about this command. I think i have to set this option to start receiving packets.

```
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP, array("group"=>"239.194.0.73","interface"=>"eth0","source"=>"239.194.0.73"));
$binded = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 6073);
```

//receive data

```
$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, MSG_WAITALL, $from, $port);
echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: are you using php >= 5.4.x ?

Comment: Here is the m3u format for IP and port.
#EXTINF:0,News
udp://@239.194.0.73:6073

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$binded = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 6073);
```

Should be

```
$binded = socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 6073);
```

Or else you will only recv packets originating from the local host.

Comment: I tried 0.0.0.0 earlier but at that time i was not using socket_set_option command. I will retry it today to see if i get any success.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
$binded = socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 6073);
$rval = socket_set_option($socket, getprotobyname("ip"), MCAST_JOIN_GROUP, array("group"=>"239.194.0.73","interface"=>0));
$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, MSG_WAITALL, $from, $port);
echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;